# Utilities to view web page as text only?

Tags: browser, web, readability

I'd like to view web pages as text only on occasion, without images or fancy css backgrounds appearing.  Are there any Mozilla or IE plugins that allow this?  I've used Readability, and it's not bad but it still downloads pictures.

Just wondering what's out there.  Thanks!

Comment: I thought most browsers allow you to disable image downloading in their options.

Comment: what version of Windows and IE your are running ?

Comment: I'd like to (if possible) not have to manually enable/disable image downloading in the browser.  Also I'd like the text to be as plain as possible, with no css in the way.

Answer (score 4):

How about  [Lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/) ?

Comment: ahhhh Lynx, the browser from 1992 that's still being updated, and it supports the Gopher protocol too.

Comment: And which is still used on occasion. :)

Answer (score 1):

In [Opera](http://www.opera.com), the [View bar](http://help.opera.com/Windows/10.51/en/toolbars.html) allows you to switch between [Author mode and User mode](http://www.opera.com/support/kb/view/778/). In user mode, you can choose which "fancy" elements you want to use or not (the default being a basic text mode).

You can also choose to not retrieve images at all, or use images from the cache only, in the same bar.

Comment: Sounds interesting.  Thanks...don't suppose IE or Firefox have anything at all similar?

Comment: @Jim - I guess there are probably extensions in Firefox to do a similar thing, but I'm not really using it, so I can't really recommend you something.

Answer (score 0):

There are several text only browsers which are still actively used.

Examples:

- [W3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/)
- Lynx
- links